# using sql 'like' statement instead of many to one relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, relational-database

I'm a beginner in Laravel and generally in relational tables and I'm not sure about using Laravel relations.
Imagine that we have a table which contains cars. each car has a country of origin. I think that I can insert name of the country in every record (car) and also I can create another table for countries and make a many to one relation in Laravel and set a country for each car in my table. what is the problem with the first choice?

I was thinking that the second one could be a better way to search throw cars by countries but we can do it with a 'like' statement in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer as an sql question since I don't use Laravel.

You need 2 tables: car and country. If you insert the name of countries on car table you have duplication of the name and in case of typo you have to update the country record misspelled and all car records with the same mistake. Moreover if you delete a country you could end up with an inconsistency: the country deleted may remain on car table.

You can use the like statement after doing a join of the two tables:

```
SELECT cars.*, country.name
FROM cars, country
WHERE cars.id_country = country.id
AND country.name LIKE 'A%'
```

(you find all the country starting by 'A').

I imagine the two table as:

- cars(..., int id_country, ...)   <- no country name here!
- country(counter id, varchar(64) name, ...)

where cars.id_country references country(id): id_country is a 'foreign key' for 'primary key' country.id (you can find everywhere this definitions if you need them and how to declare them in every dbms).